# Most Unique Thing We Can Get From Mobile with react native

Tags: react-native

Nowadays I am developing mobile applications with React Native

I Want to point an Unique String for each Mobile Device

for example when I call an API with these parameters

> /api/device/:ID/

iD Should Always be Unique for That Phone and Generated in React Native

Any Solution?

Comment: did you try with getDeviceId of  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Device token(A device token is an unique identifier) for unique id for each mobile.

use this library to get device token [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info)

Answer (score 2):

You can use either getDeviceId() or getDeviceToken() with this libraryr[rn-device info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-info)